# How do I re-create the calendar rules for pandas.tseries.holiday.USFederalHolidayCalendar?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to build a subset of US Federal holidays using the pandas.tseries.holiday.USFederalHolidayCalendar library. I managed to exclude some holiday rules "in-place" i.e. some holidays were permanently excluded from the class due to "pop" function applied to an object of the class. How do I undo the modifications to the rule set?

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import get_calendar, HolidayCalendarFactory, GoodFriday
cal2 = get_calendar('USFederalHolidayCalendar')
cal.rules.pop(2)
print(cal2)
```

I expected to create a subset of dates using the modified rule-set. However, accidentally I ended up permanently modifying the rules in my base class. I need some help in figuring out how to undo the effect of "pop" on the class object

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer. Simply .push('Holiday:xx') to the same list the missing holiday/custom holidays and the rule set will be set correct.